# Small application for manipulating users and their activities

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, winforms

I made a small application using `C#`, `SQL Database`, entity framework , and windows forms to manipulate users (`Add_User` , `Update_User` , `Delete_User`) and their activities (`Add_Activity` , `Update_Activity` , `Delete_Activity`). I created a database with 2 tables, the first one with users and a second one with the activities of each user. The relationship is one to many with a foreign key at the activities table which is the `User_ID` in the first table. The first Frame has the option to create a new user or to choose a user from a data grid loaded with all the users from the table and update or delete them. By double clicking at one of the users at the data grid a second Frame opens with a data grid of all the activities of that user. The code for that is:

```
void updateActions()
{
    using (I2SEntities1 db = new I2SEntities1())
        dgActions.DataSource = db.Actions.Where(x => x.Client_ID.Equals(Main.client.Client_ID)).ToList<Action>();
}
```

Where `dgActions` is the data grid in the second frame and `Main.client.Client_ID` is the `ID` of the `User`.

- My first question: Is this a good way of doing it. In order to load all the activities of the user I have to iterate to all the members in the table activities which doesn't look so good. There is an `ICollection<Actions>` in the auto generated code from entity framework , how can i make use of it?.
- My second question: If I want to delete a user, I can't do it if it has activities because of the foreign key which is normal. How would I go about doing this?

Is there another, better way, to check if a user still has activities and display a message? I can do it with a `try/catch` block or by checking if the count in the `ICollection<Action>` of the class `Client` is zero  . But is this the right away?

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to delete this user ?" , "Delete User" , MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            using (I2SEntities1 db = new I2SEntities1())
            {
                var entry = db.Entry(client);
                if (entry.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached)
                    db.Clients.Attach(client);

                if (client.Actions.Count == 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        db.Clients.Remove(client);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        MessageBox.Show("User: " + client.Name + " deleted successfully");
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                    }

                }
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Can't delete User " + client.Name + ". User has activities");



            }
            Clear();
            update_Grid();


        }
    }
```

These are my main concerns, but I would also like to know if I have a good application design.

```
namespace I2S
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
       public static Client client = new  Client();


        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }


        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clear();
        }
        void Clear()
        {
            txtName.Text = txtPhone.Text = txtAddress.Text = "";
            btnAdd.Text = "Add";
            btnDelete.Enabled = false;
            client.Client_ID = 0;
        }

        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to delete this user ?" , "Delete User" , MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                using (I2SEntities1 db = new I2SEntities1())
                {
                    var entry = db.Entry(client);
                    if (entry.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached)
                        db.Clients.Attach(client);
                    db.Clients.Remove(client);

                    db.SaveChanges();
                    MessageBox.Show("Deleted Successfully");

                }
                Clear();
                update_Grid();


            }
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            client.Name = txtName.Text.Trim();
            client.Address = txtAddress.Text.Trim();
            client.Telephone = txtPhone.Text.Trim();

            using (I2SEntities1 db = new I2SEntities1())
            {
                if (client.Client_ID == 0)
                {
                    db.Clients.Add(client);
                    db.SaveChanges();


                    MessageBox.Show("New user added");
                }
                else
                {
                    db.Entry(client).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();



                    MessageBox.Show("User Updated Successfully");
                }
                Clear();
                update_Grid();

            }


        }

        private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            update_Grid();

        }


        void update_Grid()
        {
            dgClients.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            using (I2SEntities1 db = new I2SEntities1())
            {
                dgClients.DataSource = db.Clients.ToList<Client>();


            }
        }
        private void dgClients_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

            if (dgClients.CurrentRow.Index != -1)
            {
                client.Client_ID = Convert.ToInt32(dgClients.CurrentRow.Cells["Client_ID"].Value);
            }
            using (I2SEntities1 db = new I2SEntities1())
            {
                client = db.Clients.Where(x => x.Client_ID == client.Client_ID).FirstOrDefault();
                txtName.Text = client.Name;
                txtAddress.Text = client.Address;
                txtPhone.Text = client.Telephone;

            }
            btnAdd.Text = "Update";
            btnDelete.Enabled = true;

        }
        private void dgClients_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dgClients.CurrentRow.Index != -1)
            {
                client.Client_ID = Convert.ToInt32(dgClients.CurrentRow.Cells["Client_ID"].Value);
            }
            Form2 actionsForm = new Form2();



            actionsForm.Show();
        }




    }
}


namespace I2S
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        Action action = new Action();

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clear();
            txtDateStart.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
            txtTimeStart.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
            txtDateEnd.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
            txtTimeEnd.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;


            btDeleteAction.Enabled = false;
            updateActions();
        }

        private void dgActions_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if(dgActions.CurrentRow.Index != -1)
            {
                action.Action_Id = Convert.ToInt32(dgActions.CurrentRow.Cells["Action_ID"].Value);
            }
            using (I2SEntities1 db = new I2SEntities1())
            {
                action = db.Actions.Where(x => x.Action_Id == action.Action_Id).FirstOrDefault();
                txtActionDescription.Text = action.Action_Desc;
                txtDateStart.Text = action.Action_Beggin.Date.ToString();
                txtTimeStart.Text = action.Action_Beggin.TimeOfDay.ToString();
                txtDateEnd.Text = action.Action_End.Date.ToString();
                txtTimeEnd.Text = action.Action_End.TimeOfDay.ToString();
            }
            btAddAction.Text = "Update";
            btDeleteAction.Enabled = true;

        }

        private void btDeleteAction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to delete this action ?", "Delete Action", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                using (I2SEntities1 db = new I2SEntities1())
                {
                    var entry = db.Entry(action);
                    if (entry.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached)
                        db.Actions.Attach(action);
                    db.Actions.Remove(action);
                    MessageBox.Show("Action Sucesfully Removed");

                    db.SaveChanges();

                }
                Clear();
                updateActions();
            }
        }

        private void btAddAction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            action.Action_Desc = txtActionDescription.Text.Trim();

            action.Action_Beggin = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDateStart.Value.Date + txtTimeStart.Value.TimeOfDay);
            action.Action_End = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDateEnd.Value.Date + txtTimeEnd.Value.TimeOfDay);
            action.Client_ID = Main.client.Client_ID;

            using (I2SEntities1 db = new I2SEntities1())
            {
                if (action.Action_Id == 0)
                {
                    db.Actions.Add(action);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    MessageBox.Show("New action added");
                }
                else
                {
                    db.Entry(action).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;


                    db.SaveChanges();

                    MessageBox.Show("Action Succesfully Updated");
                }
            }
            Clear();
            updateActions();

        }
        void updateActions()
        {
            using (I2SEntities1 db = new I2SEntities1())
                dgActions.DataSource = db.Actions.Where(x => x.Client_ID.Equals(Main.client.Client_ID)).ToList<Action>();
        }



        private void btClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clear();
        }
        void Clear()
        {
            txtActionDescription.Text = txtDateStart.Text =  txtTimeStart.Text = txtDateEnd.Text = txtTimeEnd.Text= "";
            btDeleteAction.Enabled = false;
            btAddAction.Text = "Add";
            action.Action_Id = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The DTO's for `Client` and `Actions` :

```
    namespace I2S
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Client
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Client()
        {
            this.Actions = new HashSet<Action>();
        }

        public int Client_ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Telephone { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Action> Actions { get; set; }
    }
}


namespace I2S
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Action
    {
        public int Action_Id { get; set; }
        public string Action_Desc { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Action_Beggin { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Action_End { get; set; }
        public int Client_ID { get; set; }

        public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace I2S
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class I2SEntities1 : DbContext
    {
        public I2SEntities1()
            : base("name=I2SEntities1")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Action> Actions { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to reviewers, if you showed the DTO's for `Client` and `Action` - and the database context. Are you using code first or db first when maintaining your database?

Comment: @Henrik Hansen For the database context shall I printScreen it? What do you mean by code first or db first?

Comment: No, I just mean the code for `I2SEntities1`

Comment: **Code first**:you create the data model as classes in C# and use [migrations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/) to create the database. **db first**: You create your database - tables ect. - in SQL Server "by hand".

Comment: I create my database in SQL "by hand" and than i used entity framework for the classes.

Answer (score 1):

So for anyone that might find it interesting: I found how to make it more efficient. 
I used as data source for my data grid this:

```
dgActions.DataSource = db.Actions.Where(
    x => x.Client_ID.Equals(Main.client.Client_ID)).ToList<Action>();
```

But in my opinion that is not so efficient. 
So I thought to use the navigation property of the class `Client` as data source.
I pass a `client_ID` from the first form. 
Create a new `Client` object and copy the one from the data base that has the same `Client_ID` passed from the previous form and use the navigation property of that object as data source.
I think this is a better implementation:

```
void updateActions()
{
    using (I2SEntities1 db = new I2SEntities1())
    {
        myClient = db.Clients.Where(x 
            => x.Client_ID == Main.client.Client_ID).FirstOrDefault();
        dgActions.DataSource = myClient.Actions.ToList<Action>();
    }
}
```

Comment: _in my opinion that is not so efficient._ - efficiency doesn't care about opinions :-P this needs to be proven with a benchmark ;-]

Comment: @t3chb0t You are right. But in this case it looks obvious. In the first case I had to iterate over the hole table to find the data that I needed and in the other case I just use the ones at the IColection. I am not familiar with this kind of programing and with c#. But if I would compare it with the complexity of an algorithm in the first case it would be O(n) where n number of members in an array and in the second case O(k) where k size of bucket of the unordered associative container. where 1 < k < n ;